# How would I reference a user account on bigcommerce so that they don't need 2 logins?

Tags: api, bigcommerce

I have shop.domain.com, and in www.domain.com i have some social stuff going on with a blog, etc. I want users to be able to post comments on the blog, and use the social features without having to maintain 2 separate logins.

Can/should I use the webhook to capture their info when they register and send it my way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Webhooks are intended for what you are attempting to do. If you look at the events that Bigcommerce webhooks support

http://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/webhooks/quickstart

The majority of the events are transactional. You can subscribe for events when a customer is created, but there is no way for you to get a notification when somebody logs into your store.

Can't you include custom javascript in the store template that lets someone connect their Facebook or Twitter account, which can also be used to comment on your blog?